# Excel - calculate mean of cells defined by another worksheet

Tags: excel, mean

I need to calculate mean values of a certain trait of host species belonging to a certain insect species. My insects here just called species are organized like shown in figure Sheet 1. Column mean_trait_of_hosts should calculate the mean trait value of the host_species 1 to 5

Sheet1
[image: Sheet1]

The host species are organized like shown in figure Sheet 2 and are located in a seperate sheet, same document.
So what I think I need is a function which looks for host species in columns B:F of the corresponding row in sheet 1 and then calculate the mean of these species using the values of sheet2. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this in Excel.

Sheet2

[image: Sheet2]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(B2:F2<>"",LOOKUP($B2:$F2,Sheet2!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",Sheet2!A:A)),Sheet2!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",Sheet2!A:A)))))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Caveats:

1. The list on Sheet2 must be sorted ascending on column A.
2. If the lookup is not on the list it will return the previous value alphabetically.

[image]

---

To deal with the second caveat above we can add another IF to test if they are on the list prior to doing the mean:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,$B2:$F2,Sheet2!A:A,"<>"))<>SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN($B2:$F2)>0)),"Host(s) not in list",AVERAGE(IF(B2:F2<>"",LOOKUP($B2:$F2,Sheet2!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",Sheet2!A:A)),Sheet2!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",Sheet2!A:A))))))
```

This is still an array formula.  Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

The data on Sheet2 must still be sorted ascending on column A.

[image]